# Output of an intermediate layer in keras passing as input a DirectoryIterator

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

Is there a way to get the output of a intermediate layer in Keras passing a DirectoryIterator as input?

I've already read the [documentation of Keras related to this](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452353/obtaining-output-of-an-intermediate-layer-in-tensorflow-keras) but as far as I undertood, those approaches use single samples as input.

I want to do this because it is more simple than read sample by sample and less computationally expensive than put everything on memory.

I'm using TensorFlow as backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
desiredOutputs = model.get_layer('layer_name').outputs #or model.layers[n].outputs
partialModel = Model(model.inputs,desiredOutputs)
```

Then use `partialModel` to `fit` or `predict` with the directory iterator.