# How to convert tf.Tensor from max pooling layer into numpy array?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, activation

The steps

```
layer_name = 'avg_pool'
activations = result_model.get_layer(layer_name).get_output_at(0)
```

give activations which are of following datatype.

How can I obtain the values from it or convert it to numpy aray? The goal is to obtain the intermediate outputs from this layer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtaining output of an Intermediate layer in TensorFlow/Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452353/obtaining-output-of-an-intermediate-layer-in-tensorflow-keras)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your problem meaning. Do you just want to get value from Tensor? If so, it can be derived easily by `activations.eval()` or `sess.run(activations)`. Make sure you have created session by `sess = tf.Session()`.

While you are debugging tensorflow codes, I suggest you to turn on eager execution mode by put `tf.enable_eager_execution()` after importing tensorflow. Which will make tensorflow derive values of Tensors in-place.