# How do i get the feature map of keras CNN model?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to know if there is a way to **retrieve/save the feature map** results on the CNN model. I also want to add the **threshold = 0.03**, how can I do it? Here is my code

```
face_train_generator = face_train_gen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/train/face_train/',
    target_size=(38, 38),
    batch_size=64,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    class_mode="categorical"
)

face_valid_generator = face_test_gen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/test/face_test/',
    target_size=(38, 38),
    batch_size=64,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    class_mode="categorical"
)
```

```
face_emotion_model = Sequential()

face_emotion_model.add(Conv2D(6, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(38, 38, 1)))
face_emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

face_emotion_model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(18, 18, 6)))
face_emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

face_emotion_model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(8, 8, 1)))
face_emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

face_emotion_model.add(Flatten())
```

```
face_train = face_emotion_model.fit_generator(
    face_train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch= 776 // 64,
    epochs=50,
    validation_data=face_valid_generator,
    validation_steps= 181 // 64  
)
```

I want to save the feature map results and will merge the feature maps from my other CNN models

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Obtaining output of an Intermediate layer in TensorFlow/Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452353/obtaining-output-of-an-intermediate-layer-in-tensorflow-keras)